# Calculate reward percentage based on individual contributions and total number of contributors.

Tags: percentages

Please feel free to correct the title. I know it's confusing.

I have the following scenario:

- contributions to project by agent A = 2
- contributions to project by **agent B = 33**
- contributions to project by agent C = 190
- contributions to project by agent D = 5
- contributions to project by **agent E = 33**
- project made $5000

What is the formula to calculate the percentage of those $5000 that each of the above agents should be rewarded with, based on the number of contributions that each of them made ?

I'm looking for a generic formula, not one that applies to my scenario only.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: I completely agree with the answer of Some Guy, and would like to off an alternative (intuitive) perspective.  The total contributions were $(263)$.  Suppose the project grossed $(263)$, so that the project exactly broke even.  Then, the fair result would be that everyone gets their money back.  This is consistent with the answer of Some Guy, because this scenario (**also**) involves distributing the proceeds in the relative proportions of $(2), (33), (190), (5), (33).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add up the total number of contributions. Now, for each person, divide the number of contributions they did by the total number of contributions. This gives you the portion of the work they did. Then you multiply this portion by $\$5000$, because they obviously should be paid in proportion to how much work they do right?

So, for your example, the total number of contributions is $2+33+190+5+33 = 263$ contributions. Now, let's determine how much $A$ should earn. They did $2$ contributions, which isn't much compared to the groups $263$. $A$ did $\frac{2}{263}$ of the work, thus they should only earn $\frac{2}{263}$ of the profit of $\$5000$. So, $A$ should get $\frac{2}{263} * 5000 \approx \$38.02$. You can apply this method to everyone else to get their earnings.

Comment: Ok for some reason I thought that because I had some people with the same contributions that that would mess up the formula that you suggested. Thanks it works fine!